# Find the distance from the point to the line

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the distance from the point $P(3,-1,4)$ and the line whose parametric equations are: $x=-2 + 3t$, $y=-2t$, and $z=1+4t$

I'm not completely sure how to solve this so I first gave the parameter $t$ some initial values:

$t=0 = Q(-2,0,1)$

$t=1 = R(1,-2,5)$

$\overrightarrow {QR} = \langle 1+2, -2-0,5-1\rangle = \langle 3,-2,4 \rangle$

$\overrightarrow {QP} = \langle 3+2, -10-, 4-1\rangle = \langle 5, -1,3 \rangle$

$\overrightarrow {QR} \times \overrightarrow {QP} = -2i+11j+7k$

$d=\frac{|\overrightarrow {QR} \times \overrightarrow {QP}|}{|\overrightarrow {QR}|} = \frac{\sqrt{166}}{\sqrt{21}}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you want the shortest distance between the point and the line? Otherwise the answer is fairly open.

Comment: The question doesn't specify, but if I did what would I do differently?

Comment: Your Q and R are two arbitrary points on the line. Unless the question asks for the shortest distance there isn't any meaning to "find the distance"? Usually these type of questions ask for (or mean to ask for) the shortest distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying distance formula gives: $D=\sqrt{(-2+3t-3)^2+(-2t+1)^2+(1+4t-4)^2}$

$$D^2=29t^2-58t+35$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}D^2=58t-58$$

So minimum distance when $t=1$.

Subbing this back in gives: $D_{min}=\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S(-2+3t,-2t,1+4t)$ be a point on the line such that $PS$ is perpendicular to the line.

Then, we have $\vec{PS}=(-2+3t-3,-2t-(-1),1+4t-4)=(3t-5,-2t+1,4t-3)$. This is perpendicular to the vector $(3,-2,4)$, we have
$$(3t-5)\cdot 3+(-2t+1)\cdot(-2)+(4t-3)\cdot 4=0\iff t=1.$$

Thus, the minimum distance is the distance between $S(1,-2,5)$ and $P(3,-1,4)$, i.e.
$$\sqrt{(1-3)^2+(-2+1)^2+(5-4)^2}=\color{red}{\sqrt{6}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

You can solve tis problem in two ways :

1) For a generic point of the line
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2+3t\\
-2t\\
1+4t
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
take the squared distance from $P$ and you have a function: $f(t)=\overline{PX}^2$. Find the minimum of this function and this is the searched distance.

2)
Take the plane orthogonal to the line and passing thorough $P$ ,i.e. the plane:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-2\\
4
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x-3\\
y+1\\
z-4
\end{bmatrix}=0
$$
the searched distance is the distance between $P$ and the intersection point of this plane with the line.